# Chrome ONLY - flickering when sizing and position with jquery + jqueryui

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Below is my code - When i am scrolling in chrome the divs flicker out of place and revert. but IE, Safari. & FF do not have this issue - any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I want a smooth site flow with only the one div scrolling - site is being used for marketing purposes. Thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body id="body">
    <div id="Header">HEADER CONTENT</div>

            <div id="Left">
                <div id="left-content">LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />LEFT CONTENT<br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                RIGHT CONTENT
            </div>
    <script>
    $( window ).on("load resize", function() {
    $( "#Header" ).position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "center-500 top",
      of: "#body"
    });
    $( "#Left" ).position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "center-500 top+100",
      of: "#body"
    });
    $('#right').css({'height':(($(document).height()))+'px'});
    $( "#right" ).position({
      my: "right top",
      at: "center+500 top",
      of: "#body"
    });

    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: BTW im running Version 31.0.1650.26 - not sure if this occurs in all chrome versions

Comment: CSS: 'body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}#Left {
 width: 650px;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
 z-index:1;
}
#right {
 width: 350px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #AAAAAA; 
}

#Header {
 background-color: #00FF00;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100px;
 width: 650px;
 z-index: 5;
}'

Comment: FIXED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Its a jQuery Glitch - go Back to ...

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Its a jQuery Glitch - go Back to ...

`<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>; <script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>;`